# How to update SceneKit nodes to 'automatically' reflect underlying model?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, scenekit, reactive-cocoa

What is the most sensible way of locating, updating, and/or adding or removing SceneKit nodes that correspond to an underlying model when that model is updated?

I'm not sure how best to word this question, so it's probably easier to have a minimal example:

I have something, let's say a collection of coloured objects, that I might want to either represent two dimensionally as squares using say, Quartz, or three dimensionally using SceneKit. Since the underlying data is the same in both cases, it seems more appropriate to abstract away the model and define something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    var uid: String
    var color: UIColor
    var position: [Float] // array of 3 floats for x, y, z
}
```

and then I have:

```
var collectionOfFoo: [Foo]
```

and then I can construct my SceneKit scene by looping over my `collectionOfFoo` and creating a `SCNBox` for each one with the appropriate colour and position etc.

Problem: the user might add a new `Foo` to the `collectionOfFoo`, or delete an existing `Foo`, or change one of an existing `Foo`'s stored values, and then the SceneKit scene has to be updated to reflect that. Destroying the scene and rebuilding it from scratch seems wasteful and would be far far too slow. This might need to be called hundreds of times per second.

My current approach: I give the SceneKit node corresponding to a given `Foo` a name that matches the `Foo`'s `uid`, and then just end up manually searching the node hierarchy using `childNodeWithName`. However, this really doesn't scale very well (poor frame rates), and it feels "wrong" as if there's probably a much easier/more idiomatic way of doing this. I've been looking at things like `ReactiveCocoa` because it seems like it solves this sort of problem, but I'm not sure if that's over-complicating things.

If I were using Objective-C, I might try creating a `Foo` class where each instance just holds a pointer to the relevant SceneKit node; this wouldn't be very elegant but would at least be efficient and would give the desired results. I'm just looking for a better way of doing it and one that works in Swift.

Suggestions are very welcome, and much appreciated–I'm still working on my first app and still consider myself a beginner at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you having a look at this course by Stanford University and having a look at the MVC lectures: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099

They recommend using `NSNotification`s to alert your controller (which in your case could be your `SCNScene`) of changes in your model. Your controller then goes and makes changes to the its view (or `SCNNode`s in your case). Here's an example:

**1.** Something happens in your model - a new `Foo` is created! Therefore, post an `NSNotification`:

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.postNotificationName("FooWasCreatedNotification",
                                        object: nil,
                                        userInfo: ["Foo": fooInstance])
```

(To be able to pass an instance of `Foo` here, `Foo` needs to be a class because `struct`s cannot be added to `userInfo`)

**2.** In your `SCNScene` (or whatever else you're using), receive the `NSNotification` and update:

```
func didRevieveNewFooNotification(notification: NSNotification!) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>,
       let foo  = info["Foo"] as? Foo {

        //  Create new node using foo's properties...
        //  And add it to the array:
        collectionOfFoo.append(foo)
    }
}
```

Using `NSNotification` makes your model very portable since `NSNotification` is blind communication. Therefore your controller and nodes can be whatever you want without having to change the model.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Swift, so most of this might be wrong, but here's a wild guess:

Why not switch to `Class` instead of `Struct`? Your code won't change that much but it will help you store an SCNNode, as well as any other graphical representation along with the data you have.

If this is not possible, how about using a separate dictionary? Just store your SCNNodes with the uid you already have:

```
var nodes = [String: SCNNode]()

...

nodes[current.uid] = aNewNode
```

You can also add and remove nodes from the Scene at anytime, no need to "destroy and rebuild". If we keep my previous example, you can simply do :

```
nodes[uidToDelete].removeFromParentNode()
```

On a side note, poor framerate might not be related to how you add/remove nodes. Try to [enable statistics on your scene](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/showsStatistics) and see where you're loosing time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. Ideally, I'd like to keep the representation completely separate from the model though if possible; it'll make my life easier down the road. If I've got references to SceneKit in a `Foo` class, it makes it significantly less portable. The framerate hit was definitely from my `childNodeWithName` calls--in some instances a change to the model would cause a cascade of updates in the SceneKit representation, and it'd result in searching for hundreds of nodes that may or may not actually exist, which is why it seemed like a bad approach.

Comment: In that case, just storing the nodes in a Dictionary should do the trick.